# loading full calendar resource form database

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i m using fullcalendar in my application.is there a way so that i can bind the resources name form the database?here is my code that contains hard-coded resource values:

```
$('#cal').fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function () {
            alert('a day has been clicked!');
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceDay',
        weekends: false,
        height: 400,
     enter code here   contentHeight: 400,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today,month',
            center:`enter code here` 'title',
            right: 'resourceDay'
        },
        resources: [
        {
            name: 'Pearl',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'Diamond',
            id: 2
        },
        {
            name: 'Topaz',
            id: 3
        },
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! there's always a way ... did you read the documentation? which way do you prefer? ajax-loading (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) or injection upon init (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/)? did you search the web for any examples?

Comment: i used a ashx file for json feed as in (arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed) but its not working.i m using the forked version of "fullcalendar with resources"

Comment: "but its not working" - how do you experience that? any console logs? any errors? any exceptions? please add some demo response from your .ashx-handler and/or a fully (not) working example :)

Comment: i mean only a plain calendar gets displayed,the data is not binded with the appropriate resources

Comment: you are not fully responding to my questions :) any console logs? any errors? any exceptions? please add some demo response from your .ashx-handler and/or a fully (not) working example